# Access Pandas Series item with dot notation like DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to access Series item via dot notation instead of bracket notation ?

```
s = pandas.Series(dict(a=4, b=4))
print s['a']  # works
print s.a     # fails
```

As we can do with DataFrame :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([dict(a=4, b=4), dict(a=4, b=4)])
print df['a']  # works
print df.a     # works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the behaviour by overloading the Series.__get_attr__ method :

```
def my__getattr__(self, key):
    # If attribute is in the self Series instance ...
    if key in self:
        # ... return is as an attribute
        return self[key]
    else:
        # ... raise the usual exception
        raise AttributeError("'Series' object has no attribute '%s'" % key)

# Overwrite current Series attributes 'else' case
pandas.Series.__getattr__ = my__getattr__
```

Then I can access Seriee items with attributes :

```
xx = pandas.Series(dict(a=44, b=55))
xx.a
```

Answer (score -1):

Not possible. You could convert the Series to a one-column DataFrame.

Comment: Sure, be not very _processing_ effective !